# reactjs bind clickhandler to array elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this problem that I am struggling with: I can't seem to bind clickhandlers to the buttons that I'm creating from my array.

This is my code:

```
 var keywords = $.map(this.props.keywords, function(keywords, company) {

            var keywordsArray = [];
            $.map(keywords, function(keyword) {
                count++;
                var key = keyword + count;
                var item = <Button onClick={this.clickKeyword} style={{margin:"3px"}} key={key}>{keyword}</Button>
                keywordsArray.push(item);
            });

            i++;
            return (
                <Tab key={i} eventKey={i} title={company}>{keywordsArray}</Tab>
            )
        },this);
```

I have also tried:

```
onClick={() => this.clickKeyword()}
```

But it keeps giving me following error:
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clickKeyword' of undefined"

I appreciate all kinds of help!

Comment: I am not familiar with  reactjs... but i think `this.` does not  contain clickkeyword() function  or  u  have  make mistake writing a spelling. maybe  camalcase : clickKeyword() instead clickKeyword();

Comment: I think problem with scope in $.map

Comment: Why are you using jQuery? instead of native `Array.prototype` methods ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all of your responses!
This fixed it:

```
 var keywords = Object.keys(this.props.keywords).map(function(company) {
            var keywordsArray = [];
            this.props.keywords[company].map(function(keyword) {
                count++;
                var key = keyword + count;
                var item = <Button onClick={this.clickKeyword.bind(null,keyword)} style={{margin:"3px"}} key={key}>{keyword}</Button>
                keywordsArray.push(item);
            },this);

            i++;
            return (
                <Tab key={i} eventKey={i} title={company}>{keywordsArray}</Tab>
            )

        },this);
```

Should have treated it as an object instead, doh! :)

Answer (score 2):

Example without using *jQuery* & [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/408/)

```
class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        items: [{id:1, name:'Hello'},{id:2, name:'World'},
               {id:3, name:'React'},{id:4, name:'Example'}]
    };

  }
  click(item){
    alert(item)
  }
  render(){
    const list = this.state.items.map((item,index) => {
        return <li key={index} onClick={this.click.bind(this,item.name)}>{item.name}</li>
    })
    return <ul>
        {list}
    </ul>
  }
}

React.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Hope it will help you.
Thanks

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, however it doesn't work as it is a multi-dimensional array

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative to @The's answer above. This allows you to make the component stateless which is preferred in React. [Fiddle|http://jsfiddle.net/kwelch/q8bfvuxv/2/]

```
const buildClickHandler = (item) => () => {
    alert(item.name);
}

const state = [{id:1, name:'Hello'},
{id:2, name:'World'},
{id:3, name:'React'},
{id:4, name:'Example'}];


class Example extends React.Component {
  render(){
    const list = this.props.items.map((item,index) => {
        return <li key={index} onClick={buildClickHandler(item)}>{item.name}</li>
    })
    return <ul>
        {list}
    </ul>
  }
}

React.render(<Example items={state} />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Unfortunately, fiddle will not let me make the component fully stateless, but this should be enough info.